# AWS ELB- multiple URL pointing to same listener

Tags: amazon-web-services

My question is specific to AWS ELB. currently I have configured AWS ELB with one listener on 443. my requirement  is to have multiple domains name pointing to same listener [ I have wild card certificate for my domain ].All the FQDN will have a same ELB name which is mapped using alias. can anybody tell me how to configure that. I believe this is similar to HAPROXY ACL configuraiton.

Comment: Will each of the aliases point to the same backing servers, or are you looking for how to route different aliases to different servers?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html  - summary: SNI doesn't work  However, it might be worth looking at ALB https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: Thanks,Host-Based Routing Support for AWS will help for my requirement.